# Can't have a reliable connection between my mobile devices and my TV both through Chromecast and Apple TV

Tags: google-home, wifi, chromecast

I have a Chromecast and Apple TV connected to a Phillips TV through the HDMI ports. The Wi-Fi router is on another room on the same floor. The devices are Android phone and iPad Mini.

I was able to setup the Chromecast but can't broadcast anything. The Apple TV is able to connect to the iPad but not always I'm able to connect it and when I do it, after few minutes the connection is lost.

My router is a single band router. I don't know where start looking first but I think that I should start looking on the router settings. How do I establish a reliable connection?

Answer (score 6):

Your router most likely can't handle the number of devices on your network. So in attempts to give every device a connection, it cycles through existing, dormant connections and boots them. In this case, your TV devices.

**I'd recommend upgrading your router.**

I've personally updated my network hardware to a [Mesh network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesh_networking) because I was encountering the same issue. This helps offset loads on a single router and distributes it across multiple, for me.

If you have many wireless devices (including Chromecast, Apple TV, Nest, Cell phones, etc.), basically anything that connects to Wi-Fi, then you'll need a stronger signal to help reach all the devices.